# About client/server Peachtree Accountant software

Tags: accounting

We plan to setup client and server for peachtree accounting system.

currently, we have software Sage Peachtree Quantum 2010 Accountant, so could we use this 
software for making client and server?

Do you have any ideas regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the Quantum still uses the pervasive database, it uses the server side database to lock the files, and is very active. Depending upon your latency of connection it may or may not work out.  We used Peachtree Compete 2004 and were successful in connecting by VPN, with a mapped drive to the datapath, nut it was very slow, albeit the connections were very slow back then.  So this is a no answer answer, just an encouragement to setup a VPN and give it a try.  Our last current version is Peachtree apremium, and it will not run this way, nor will it run under terminal services, which is an alternate solution.  However, I am told that the latest versions will run under terminal services, as we are considering upgrading to such.   Sage's tech support is junk, so do not look directly to them for much help, however there are a lot of good VAR support companies that vary in competence and may be good for some assistance.  Good luck.